# DCT and IDCT implementation in Java for 2-dimensional matrix

Tags: java, performance, optimization

I already have an implementation for both the dct and idct, however they become very slow as the size of the matrix increases despite proper optimization.
Does anyone know a faster implementation for both or any Java library that provides a faster implementation for a 2-dimensional case.
Thanks

```
 public final double[][] initCoefficients(double[][] c) 
 {
    final int N = c.length;
    final double value = 1/Math.sqrt(2.0);

    for (int i=1; i<N; i++) 
    {
        for (int j=1; j<N; j++) 
        {
            c[i][j]=1;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
    {
        c[i][0] = value;
        c[0][i] = value;
    }
    c[0][0] = 0.5;
    return c;
}

/* Computes the discrete cosine transform
 */
public final double[][] forwardDCT(double[][] input) 
{
    final int N = input.length;
    final double mathPI = Math.PI;
    final int halfN = N/2;
    final double doubN = 2.0*N;

    double[][] c = new double[N][N];
    c = initCoefficients(c);

    double[][] output = new double[N][N];

    for (int u=0; u<N; u++) 
    {
        double temp_u = u*mathPI;
        for (int v=0; v<N; v++) 
        {
            double temp_v = v*mathPI;
            double sum = 0.0;
            for (int x=0; x<N; x++) 
            {
                int temp_x = 2*x+1;
                for (int y=0; y<N; y++) 
                {
                    sum += input[x][y] * Math.cos((temp_x/doubN)*temp_u) * Math.cos(((2*y+1)/doubN)*temp_v);
                }
            }
            sum *= c[u][v]/ halfN;
            output[u][v] = sum;
        }
    }
    return output;
}

/* 
 * Computes the inverse discrete cosine transform
 */
public final double[][] inverseDCT(double[][] input) 
{
    final int N = input.length;
    final double mathPI = Math.PI;
    final int halfN = N/2;
    final double doubN = 2.0*N;

    double[][] c = new double[N][N];
    c = initCoefficients(c);

    double[][] output = new double[N][N];


    for (int x=0; x<N; x++) 
    {
        int temp_x = 2*x+1;
        for (int y=0; y<N; y++) 
        {
            int temp_y = 2*y+1;
            double sum = 0.0;
            for (int u=0; u<N; u++) 
            {
                double temp_u = u*mathPI;
                for (int v=0; v<N; v++) 
                {
                    sum += c[u][v] * input[u][v] * Math.cos((temp_x/doubN)*temp_u) * Math.cos((temp_y/doubN)*v*mathPI);
                }
            }
            sum /= halfN;
            output[x][y] = sum;
        }
   }
   return output;
}
```

Comment: Faster than what? Show us your code ([CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java) might be better suited).

Comment: @maaartinus I added my current code for both implementation. They tend to be slow as the size of the matrix increases.

Comment: DCT is separable, you should use that. Also, Math.cos is atrociously slow and you only need a couple of values from it, so you can prepare them in an array.

Comment: @harold What do you mean by DCT being separable? Besides the code is not slow as a result of the Math class. I think it's a problem with the loop. Am working with a (512 by 512) matrix.

Comment: I mean you don't have to do a 2D DCT directly. You can construct it out of n+n 1D DCTs. And it probably is also the math class, cos is crazy slow and the main thing you're doing is taking cosines, the rest sort of disappears in the noise. Using separability gets rid of a lot of cosines already, but you can then get rid of still more.

Comment: harold is surely right with `Math.cos`. It's the most expensive operation and gets executed `2*512*512` times instead of not at all (it can be precomputed). There's also fast DCT (see wiki) which reduces the looping considerably, but this is a more complicated optimization.

Comment: Thanks guys. @harold to be sincere I do not know how to construct it out of n+n 1D DCT, will be nice if you can help with that. Also precomputing  the cosine seems difficult since am computing the cosine of the inner (loop) locals variables. Please kindly suggest by some code fragments

Answer (score 4):

Right now it's an O(n<sup>4</sup>) algorithm, four nested loops all doing `n` iterations. Separability gets that down to O(n<sup>3</sup>) (or O(n<sup>2</sup>log n) if you're feeling brave enough to try the Fast Cosine Transform). It's actually even simpler than using the 2D formula, because all it is is this:

- run 1D DCT on all rows
- run 1D DCT on all columns (of the previous result)

Or (optionally), to make both parts exactly the same:

- run 1D DCT on all rows, saving the results transposed
- just do that again

The transpose means the second time it's really doing columns, and in the two transposes undo each other.

So, the cosines. You note that

> precomputing the cosine seems difficult since am computing the cosine of the inner (loop) locals variables

Those cosines are really just constants written down in formulaic form, that array depends only on `n`. For example, look at how FFmpeg does it in [dctref.c](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.4/dctref_8c_source.html)

Comment: Nice breakdown, will give it a try as you suggested and I hope it's faster in this case.

Comment: I know this is pretty a late reply but still no progress, could not get it to work as you have explained.

Comment: @herald I tried the sample code but did not fully understand it, still have the project hanging

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a max size for the DCT? If working with integers is OK (and this is usually the case for image manipulation), you can find some fast implementations for size 4, 8, 16 and 32 there: https://github.com/flanglet/kanzi/tree/master/java/src/kanzi/transform